# How to import system backup to Artifactory using JFrog cli

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I've [run Artifactory using Docker](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation).

Downloaded [JFrog cli](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) inside the container and configured it.

So `./jfrog  rt ping` returns

> OK

Is there a way to perform [system level export/import](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Import+and+Export#ImportandExport-SystemImportandExport) using JFrog cli?

Succeeded to perform it using web ui. Couldn't find information on how to perform [system level export/import](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Import+and+Export#ImportandExport-SystemImportandExport) in the documentation.

**Edit**

Succeeded to perform export using REST API:

`curl -u admin:pass -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/tmp/export-settings.json http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/export/system`

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke the same REST API using JFrog CLI's curl command as shown below. This way, you don't need to provide the URL and credentials. JFrog CLI's config storage will be used. You can manage this storage using the `jfrog rt c` command. 
If you have multiple Artifactory severs configured, and you don't want to use the default server, the `jfrog rt curl` command also accepts the --server-id option, with the pre configured Artifactory server ID as the valve.

```
jfrog rt curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/tmp/export-settings.json api/export/system
```

Comment: thanks. though, got error: `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a permission issue. Maybe the credentials you used do not allow access to this API. Try the same with plain curl. I assume you'll get the same response, if you'll be using the same credentials as configured for JFrog CLI.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently not supported by the CLI.

Feel free to create a [feature request](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/new/choose).